# ABCPDF Alter image compression when carrying out doc.AddImageUrl

Tags: abcpdf

Using ABCPDF, currently generating pdf's with 1mb files.
When we alter the pdf in acrobat pro, and simply change the image quality this drops the size to 100K.

I have looked at the documentation for ABCPDF however I cannot find a simple example of dropping the image quality prior to saving the document, hence getting a smaller pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears simple :

doc.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 33;

Answer (score 3):

Without reviewing the code you used to create the PDF, I would strongly suggest taking a second look at it ensure you are using the `Flatten` method for your document.

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/default.html

The AbcPdf library adds objects to a page with each typically represented as an  individual layer.  When you execute the `Flatten` method all layers on the document will be removed and replaced by compressed respresentation.

Example c# code snippet:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= yourPdfDocument.PageCount; i++) {
  yourPdfDocument.PageNumber = i;
  yourPdfDocument.Flatten();
}
```